# Do MOSFETs overheat in the off state?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, power-consumption

I'm dealing with a 30N60 power MOSFET connected to a 15 A 12 V battery (acting as a switch.) Do such MOSFETs overheat or consume a lot of energy in the off state? (When the gate is off.)

Comment: No, they should not.

Comment: but when the gate is off the current passes through it and gets out of the emitter  , right ?

Comment: @Ale865 MOSFETs don't have a collector/emitter. Do you mean drain or source?

Comment: Technically a little bit of current always passes through everything, unless they are at the same potential. Also note you specifically said "a lot of energy"

Comment: ok , thanks for your help :)

Comment: It depends on the actual circuit. A lot of heat can be produced but, without the schematic it's a guess.

Comment: Compute the power yourself. Supply voltage * leakage current. The latter should be in the datasheet but it's typically microamps.

Comment: A little nitpick here- power typically will be very low, but the energy can be arbitrarily large since a tiny loss for a thousand years adds up to a lot of energy. Power is energy per unit time.

Comment: If you have a power MOSFET that is generating heat when you think it should be in the off state, maybe your gate driver circuit is not bringing Vgs all the way to 0, and the device is partly on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do such MOSFETs overheat or consume a lot of energy in the off state (when the gate is off)?

No, when the MOSFET is **off** it behaves like an open, there is no connection, no current can flow: Current = 0.

Power = Voltage x Current

so If Current = 0, Power most be 0 as well.

You don't turn on/off the Gate of a MOSFET. Instead, a MOSFET is controlled by the **voltage** \$V_{GS}\$ that is applied between Gate and Source. Most MOSFETs (and certainly the one that you use) are **off** (not conduction) when that \$V_{GS}\$ = 0.

Do be aware that when you want to switch the MOSFET **on** that you need to apply **enough** \$V_{GS}\$  for it to conduct properly. The datasheet will tell you what voltage is needed.

When a MOSFET is turned on properly the Voltage across it (\$V_{DS}\$) becomes almost zero meaning it should dissipate little power even though the current can be large.

Comment: In reality the MOSFET is OFF when Vgs is below Vgs(threshold). For the 30N60 anything below 2.5V should be OFF.

Comment: *In reality the MOSFET is OFF when Vgs is below Vgs(threshold).* Correct! However, since it is much easier to apply \$V_{GS}\$ = 0 V (just short Gate and Source) that's what we normally do. And to keep things simple I didn't mention that indeed \$V_{GS}\$ < \$V_{th}\$ is what is actually needed.